# how to start and spawn player in a room/match using Mirror?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I am new to using Mirror in Unity, and I got myself a udemy course and follow youtube tutorials, but most tutorials uses a single room or match only, but then i found this:
followed it religiously and understood the concept.
https://youtu.be/qkoZ7d6eQ8k
the tutorial is upto opening or changing a scene only for the players in a match, which is really helpful as it includes matchmaking as well.

However im finding it hard to imagine how to start the game form there on,
How do I spawn the correct player objects in the match room that will only appear on a certain room of the players involved?

Any tutorial or resource that can help is greatly appreciated